# Server Side / Cloud Coding for the app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, server-side, amazon-dynamodb

I am am making an app for iOS & Android whose frontend UI is ready. Now I wanted to learn some server side coding to connect my backend with Amazon services.

MY app will feature 1.image upload & download 2. storing of data and meta data 3. user registration and stuff

I have no clear idea about server side and cloud coding ? so want you guys push me a bit from where should I begin and how should I begin to make the above features for my app working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking to do mobile app development that works with cloud datastores.

Here are a few blogs that you can take a look at get started with:

http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxERCU1UMRFNPB/DynamoDB-on-Mobile-Part-5-Fine-Grained-Access-Control

The above blog post talks about using AWS Mobile SDKs with DynamoDB. In general, mobile.awsblog.com has more resources for developing with other datastores and might be a good resource. For DynamoDB's support for enabling mobile developers to build serverless architectures, please take a look:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/FGAC_DDB.html

Hope this helps.

Swami

Answer (score 0):

If you have no clear idea about server side coding maybe you should use a backend-as-a-service platform such as [Backbeam](http://backbeam.io). These platforms give you SDKs for iOS and Android typically and you don't have to worry about the servers stuff. You can create a database in the control panel and start using it from your iOS apps making queries, inserting data, etc. You have also other features such as push notifications, users authentication, and more.

Disclaimer: I work at Backbeam. Other well-known platforms are parse and kinvey